# JAXB not unmarshalling xml any element to JAXBElement

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a webservice call.  In my response when I try to get the xml `any` element in to a JAXBElement it throws an error.

In the schema I have:

```
<xs:complexType name="InputType">
    <xs:annotation></xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>           
        <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The code I am using:

```
Object obj = inputType.getAny();
Object o = ((JAXBElement)obj).getValue();
```

This line throws the error: `org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl incompatible with javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` error in soap ui.

Why doesn't it covert to JAXBElement?  How do I make it work?

Answer (score 10):

If the property is annotated with the following the contents will be mapped as DOM nodes:

```
@XmlAnyElement
```

If the lax=true flag is set then known elements will be converted to domain objects:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
```

For more information on @XmlAnyElement see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

---

**UPDATE #1**

With lax=true you can get a mix of domain objects and DOM nodes.  The following is from the java docs:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html#lax()

> **When true**
>
> If true, when an element
> matches a property marked with
> XmlAnyElement is known to JAXBContext
> (for example, there's a class with
> XmlRootElement that has the same tag
> name, or there's XmlElementDecl that
> has the same tag name), the
> unmarshaller will eagerly unmarshal
> this element to the JAXB object,
> instead of unmarshalling it to DOM.
> Additionally, if the element is
> unknown but it has a known xsi:type,
> the unmarshaller eagerly unmarshals
> the element to a JAXBElement, with the
> unknown element name and the
> JAXBElement value is set to an
> instance of the JAXB mapping of the
> known xsi:type.
>
> As a result, after the unmarshalling,
> the property can become heterogeneous;
> it can have both DOM nodes and some
> JAXB objects at the same time.

---

**UPDATE #2**

To ultimately solve the problem:

1. Since it is possible for that property to contain a DOM node, your code should account for this possibility by doing some type checking.
2. To reduce the amount of DOM nodes received you need to associate the possible root elements of those fragments with Java classes.  This is done by annotating classes with @XmlRootElement(name="foo", namespace="bar"), or with @XmlElementDecl.

Check out my blog for an example:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Comment: In this case it is lax=true, domain Object. But my question is around why the unmarshalling complains about the not being compatible with JAXBElement object.

Comment: You can still get DOM nodes in your property annotated with @XmlAnyElement(lax=true). See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information, how do I get the value out of this getAny(). what is the workaround?

Comment: I've updated my answer again, the trick is to associate the root element of those fragments with a Java class using @XmlRootElement or @XmlElementDecl.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but I had no luck with @XmlRootElement and most of my code is generate through tool. We had some previous code samples which worked with out doing any workarounds, the only diffrence is those were in Enumuration context and getting any value from enum Object, which is similar concept what I am trying to achieve. I am using websphere 6.1 and soap 1.7 - jaxb 2.0 - which I guess not an issue.

Comment: If there is no @XmlRootElement or @XmlElementDecl that corresponds to the XML fragment then you will get a DOM node on the any property.  If you have specified this info and you are still not getting back an instance of your domain object then there is a bug in the implementation of JAXB you are using.

Answer (score 1):

validate your xml against your schema. that should be the first thing to be checked